# System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Random' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random count = new Random();
            count.Next(1, 10);
            Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next(1, 100);
            int[] x = new int[Convert.ToInt32(count)] ;
            int summ = 0;
                                 
            for (int i = 0; i<Convert.ToInt32(count); i++)
            {
                x[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
                Console.WriteLine(x[i]);
                summ += x[i];
            }

            int average = summ / Convert.ToInt32(count);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Code image]

Comment: It would be nice if you'd asked a question. I'm guessing your problem has to do with: `Random count = new Random()` followed by `Convert.ToInt32(count)`. Why do you create two `Random` instances? Why don't you assign the results of `Random.Next` to a variable? A `Random` instance can't just be converted to an `int`

Comment: You want type 'int' for 'count' and assign it Random. Next

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding any other problems (conceptual or otherwise)

You are trying to convert the instance of your random class to the array size.

Try something like this

```
// only instantiate Random once per thread
private static Random _r = new Random();

static  void Main(string[] args)
{
   // get a random number. This will result in an int
   var size = _r.Next(1, 10);
   
   // use the int directly to instantiate the array with the size
   var array = new int[size];
```

---

The longer story.

You are calling `Convert.ToInt32` on an instance of the Random class

```
Random count = new Random()
... Convert.ToInt32(count)]
```

To do this, the type needs to implement the `IConvertable` interface, for which `Random` doesn't. Which is exactly what the error is telling you.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Random' to type
> 'System.IConvertible'.

All you need to do is get your random number

```
var size = _r.Next(1, 10);
```

And use it in the array initializer (term used loosely)

```
var array = new int[size];
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-5.0)